# how to run the program for example arguments?

Tags: java

i.e. how to enter sample data into the program to see how it works?

```
    public class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Author autor = new Author(args);
        new Thread(autor).start();
        new Thread(new Writer(autor)).start();
      }
    }
```

I mean these args

Answer (score 0):

you should javac command to compile you main class and java command to run and pass params

```
compile: javac Main.java  
run: java Main test1 test2 1 2 3
-> 5 parmas
```